# Optimal data streaming and processing solution for enormous datasets into tf.data.Dataset

Tags: tensorflow, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-transform

**Context:**

My text input pipeline currently consists of two main parts:

**I**. A complex text preprocessing and exporting of `tf.SequenceExamples` to tfrecords (custom tokenization, vocabulary creation, statistics calculation, normalization and many more over the full dataset as well as per each individual example). That is done once for each data configuration.

**II**. A tf.Dataset (TFRecords) pipeline that does quite a bit of processing during training, too (`string_split` into characters, table lookups, bucketing, conditional filtering, etc.).

Original Dataset is present across multiple locations (BigQuery, GCS, RDS, ...).

**Problem:**

The problem is that as the production dataset increases rapidly (several terabytes), it is not feasible to recreate a tfrecords files for each possible data configuration (part 1 has a lot of hyperparameters) as each will have an enormous size of hundreds of terabytes. Not to mention, that `tf.Dataset` reading speed surprisingly slows down when `tf.SequenceExamples` or tfrecords grow in size.

There are quite a few possible solutions:

- Apache Beam + Cloud DataFlow + feed_dict;
- tf.Transform;
- Apache Beam + Cloud DataFlow + tf.Dataset.from_generator;
- tensorflow/ecosystem + Hadoop or Spark
- tf.contrib.cloud.BigQueryReader

, but neither of the following seem to fully fulfill my requierments:

1. Streaming and processing on the fly data from BigQuery, GCS, RDS, ... as in part I.
2. Sending data (protos?) directly to `tf.Dataset` in one way or another to be used in part II.
3. Fast and reliable for both training and inference.
4. (optional) Being able to pre-calculate some full pass statistics over the selected part of the data.
5. **EDIT:** Python 3 support would be just wonderful.

What is the most suitable choice for the `tf.data.Dataset` pipeline? What are the best practices in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Beam now has Py3 support, and integration with tf.Transform.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to orchestrate the whole use case using [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer)(GCP integration of Airflow).

Airflow provided operators which let you orchestrate a pipeline with a script.

In your case you can use the [dataflow_operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.html) to have the dataflow job spin up when you have enough data to process.

To get the data from BigQuery you can use the [bigquery_operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.html).

Furthermore you can use the python operator or the bash operator to monitor and pre-calculate statistics.